# Value is not being appended to the list

Tags: python

Zero not being appended to the list. Also, length of my output is not 6 but 5. I don't seem to understand what is causing this.

```
c = [0.1254, .2710, .4118, 0.6639, 0.7882, 1.0]
r = [.201, .284, .099, .822, .398, .501]
idx = []

for j in r:
    for i in xrange(len(c)):
        k = (i+1) % len(c)
        if ((j > c[i]) and (j < c[k])):
            idx.append(k)
print idx
```

And the following is my output

```
[1, 2, 5, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

The 3rd loop of j in r will put j at 0.099.

The last if statement means that that j must be bigger than c[i], but there's no element in c smaller than 0.099!

Comment: Thank you so much. But if that's the case how do I append zero to my idx?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, but you could try putting this underneath the if statement:    if j < min(c): idx.append(0)

Answer (score 0):

- k= 0 only if i=5
- then for k=0: j< c[0] is only true for j = 0
- but 0 > c[i] if False for every i